# Population Growth and Ultimate Value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, problem-solving

I was given this question and am unsure how to continue:

### Question

> A population $x(t)$ grows in time according to
>   $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = (x-1)(2x-1)$. Knowing that
>   $x(0)=0$, after how much time does it reach $50\%$ of its ultimate
>   value as time passes?

### Attempt

I first converted into partial fractions:
$$\mathrm{d}t = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{(x-1)(2x-1)} \\
\mathrm{d}t = \mathrm{d}x\left(\dfrac{1}{x-1} - \dfrac{2}{2x-1}\right)$$

Then integrated to get
$$t = \ln\left|x-1\right| - \ln\left|2x-1\right| + C$$
Subbing in $x=0$ with $t=0$ (to determine $C=0$), then rearranging, I got:
$$t = \ln\left|\dfrac{x-1}{2x-1}\right|$$

My next instinct was to determine the maximum time, but after differentiating $t$ with respect to $x$, I get this, which has no solutions for $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x} = 0$:
$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x} = \dfrac{1}{(2x-1)(x-1)} = \dfrac{1}{x-1} - \dfrac{2}{2x-1}$$

As you can see, I really just went in a circle. I don't know how to continue. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$t = \ln\left|\dfrac{x-1}{2x-1}\right|$$

Looks good to me.

> My next instinct was to determine the maximum time,

Why?  Or more importantly, why should there be a “maximum time”?  The problem states:

> > after how much time does it reach $50\%$ of its ultimate value as time passes?

So think instead about finding $x_\infty = \lim_{t\to\infty} x(t)$, and then finding $t^*$ such that $x(t^*) = \frac{1}{2} x_\infty$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! The reason for my poor instinct was unfamiliarity. I'm not very familiar with finding limits, especially when I don't have an expression for $x(t)$. Would it be possible that you could provide some pointers if you know of any? Many thanks.

Comment: What is the inverse function to ln?

Comment: D'oh, that wasn't as hard as I thought. Thanks a lot for entertaining a n00b like me, it's greatly appreciated. :-)
$$x_\infty = \frac{1}{2}$$
$$t^\star = \ln\left|\dfrac{3}{2}\right|$$

Answer (score 0):

write your equation in the form
$$\frac{dx}{(x-1)(2x-1)}=dt$$ and calculate the partial decomposition:
$$\frac{1}{(x-1)(2x-1)}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{2x-1}$$